# Symfony 3 An error occurred while loading the web debug toolbar

Tags: php, symfony, profiler, symfony-3.2

Hi I have problem with debug toolbar, when I try to load page (on localhost) all code is loading correctly but after code is loaded a get warning :

> An error occurred while loading the web debug toolbar (500: Internal Server Error). Do you want to open the profiler?

I can choose : OK or Cancel.

When I click Cancel nothing happens, but if I clicked OK I get (http://127.0.0.1:8000/_profiler/ae356f):

> There are no registered paths for namespace "security".

```
{% block menu %}
        <span class="label {{ not collector.enabled or not collector.token ? 'disabled' }}">
            <span class="icon">{{ include('@security/Collector/icon.svg') }}</span>
            <strong>Security</strong>
        </span>
{% endblock %}
```

I can share Composer file:

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": { "": "src/" },
        "classmap": [ "app/AppKernel.php", "app/AppCache.php" ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": { "Tests\\": "tests/" },
        "files": [ "vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/VarDumper/Resources/functions/dump.php" ]
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
        "doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle": "^1.2",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.0.2",
        "symfony/polyfill-apcu": "^1.0",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.3.10",
        "symfony/symfony": "3.2.*",
        "twig/twig": "^1.0||^2.0",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.8.1",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "^3.0",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^3.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "symfony-scripts": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@symfony-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@symfony-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "platform": {
            "php": "5.5.9"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-bin-dir": "bin",
        "symfony-var-dir": "var",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "symfony-tests-dir": "tests",
        "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "3.2-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

Can you guys have any idea what can be cause of this problem? I already tried [this](https://github.com/silexphp/Silex-Skeleton/issues/69) solution but no effect. Please help.

Comment: Can you give us your Apache Virtual Host if any and/or `.htaccess` file? Seems to me that something is stopping the debug toolbar to work properly

Comment: Sure no problem, but which one? From Web folder?

Comment: Well if you have an Apache virtual host won't be on your web folder, if you have not made any changes to the default `.htacess` then no need to add it here

Comment: You right, I didn't change anything there.

Answer (score 0):

On the french site [openclassroom.fr](https://openclassrooms.com/forum/sujet/symfony2-le-profiler-de-symfony) a guy have the same error 500. I don't know the true hidden error but his error is

> The security context contains no authentication token. One possible
>   reason may be that there is no firewall configured for this URL.

The issue seems to be to test if a token exist:

```
if(null == $this->securityContext->getToken() && HttpKernelInterface::MASTER_REQUEST !== $event->getRequestType())
{
    return;
}
```